# Выпадающий список поверх iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, position

```
 Должно быть так:
```

[image]

а получается , что Google Chart(iframe  не дает списку выпадать):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не помогает ни z-index ни absolute

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть рабочий код

Comment: @Арсен https://jsfiddle.net/3eygq8vf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте для `.navigation li` - `position: relative` и `z-index: 9` (для примера)

Пример

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
  data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
    'p': {
      'html': true
    }
  });


  data.addRows([
    ['Spartak', new Date(2010, 05, 25), createCustomHTMLContent('Spartak', 'Simferopol', 'Kapitolij')],
    ['Oreanda', new Date(2010, 06, 10), createCustomHTMLContent('Oreanda', 'Yalta', 1)],
    ['Effekt', new Date(2010, 06, 24), createCustomHTMLContent('Effekt', 'Chernovcy', 1)],
    ['Spartak', new Date(2010, 07, 24), createCustomHTMLContent('Spartak', 'Simferopol', 'Forum')],
    ['Lukomore', new Date(2010, 09, 15), createCustomHTMLContent('Lukomore', 'Mariupol', 'Big')],
    ['Adrenalin City', new Date(2010, 12, 06), createCustomHTMLContent('Adrenalin City', 'Luck', 'Red')],
    ['Raketa', new Date(2010, 12, 16), createCustomHTMLContent('Raketa', 'Evpatoriya', 'Mars')],
    ['Bajda 3D', new Date(2010, 12, 28), createCustomHTMLContent('Bajda 3D', 'Zaporozhe', 'Big')]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    height: 450,
    lineWidth: 4,

    lineDashStyle: [15, 2, 3, 3],
    pointSize: 10,
    colors: ['#af0000'],
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    },
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 14 // or the number you want
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 14,

      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function createCustomHTMLContent(name, city, hall) {
  return '<div>' +
    '<br/>' +
    '<table class="medals_layout" style="font-family:DINPro">' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><b>Name: </b>' + name + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><b>City: </b>' + city + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><b>Hall: </b>' + hall + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '</table>' + '</div>';
}
```

```css
a:hover {
  color: #777;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #95C11F;
}

.navigation,
.navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover,
.navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.navigation a.main {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 15px/40px arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation:hover a.main {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.navigation li {
  position: relative; /* по умолчанию static*/
  z-index: 9; /* if static - z-index не работает */
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.navigation li.n1 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
}

.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
}

.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}

.navigation li.n4 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
}

.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.navigation:hover .n5 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n1"><a href="#">2010</a></li>
  <li class="n2"><a href="#">2011</a></li>
  <li class="n3"><a href="#">2012</a></li>
  <li class="n4"><a href="#">2013</a></li>
  <li class="n5"><a href="#">2014</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно задать у обоих dom объектов (ul class="navigation" и div id="chart_div") position: relative, и добавить 1-му z-index